# How to apply multiple filters on a dstore?

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

Let's say that a `dstore` has records with First name, Last name and Age. Now, I want records with First name as "Name1" OR Age= 25. How can I do this in `dstore`?
If I do, 
`recordStore.filter({name: 'Name1'}, {age: 25});`
then it returns the records having name as "Name1" AND Age=25.

Another question, in the records of my `dstore`, there is an array also (comprising of colours). I want to filter the results based on the colours selected by the user. The problem that I face is that `dstore.filter()` checks for the complete matching of the value, but I want to retain the record if even one value in the array matches with the selected value. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

`Filter` objects can be created from the `store` and then used as arguments to `filter` method of the `store`.

For doing OR/ AND of two queries:

```
recordStoreFilter= new recordStore.Filter()
name1Filter= recordStoreFilter.eq('name': 'Name1')
age25Filter= recordStoreFilter.eq('age', 25)

unionFilter= recordStoreFilter.or(name1Filter, age25Filter)
intersectionFilter= recordStoreFilter.and(name1Filter, age25Filter)

unionData= recordStore.filter(unionFilter)
intersectionData= recordStore.filter(intersectionFilter)

//Set using the following
recordGrid.set('collection', unionData) //or intersectionData
```

To match one value from an array:

```
colorFilter= recordStoreFilter.contains({'color', 'red'})
colorData= recordStore.filter(colorFilter)
//This will give the records that have color red in the array.
```

For more, see [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md).

Comment: I think eq() expects a key and value, e.g. recordStoreFilter.eq('name', 'Name1') and not an object. Otherwise very helpful.

Comment: @Simon: thanks for pointing. You are right. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend the filter function like this:

```
recordStore.filter( function (object) {
    return object.Name === 'Name1' || object.age === 25;
});
```